# how to define a function with inputted image as parameter?

Tags: python, function

I'm very new to python, so please bear with me. I have an assignment for which I have to make a function that crops an inputted image, however I can't get the function to recognize the input as an image, and the im.shape call isn't working.

EDIT: changed a bunch, having the function recognize the input as a string, and a tuple out of range error

This is what I have for the function:

```
def make_square(im):
    h = im.size[0]
    w = im.size[1]
    if w > h:
        w = w - (h-w)
    elif h > w: 
        h = h - (w-h)
    im = im.crop((w, h))
    print(im)
```

and this is what I have when I call it:

```
from PIL import Image
from check2_helper import make_square

im1 = Image.open('ca.jpg')
imsquare = make_square(im1)
imsquare.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you passing as `im`?

Comment: @kindall i am passing im as the inputted image, i think? like when i call the function, instead of (im) it would be ('pic.jpg') - I had it as image as first, but after playing around for a bit i ended up leaving it as im

Comment: What is the "inputted image"? Is it a filename? A pathname? A file object? An image you have read from a file? What I'm asking for is an example of how you're calling it, including how you set that value.

Comment: @kindall oh okay I'm sorry! we were given a set of .jpg files to call for the function to crop them, so I believe its a file object? when calling this function, I've been calling it as: make_square('imagename.jpg'),  but i'm getting the error "AttributeError: shape"

Comment: @kindall after importing make_square, should I be defining the .jpg file as a variable before calling the function? - I just tried that and I'm getting "AttributeError: read"

Comment: Images in Pillow don't have a `shape` attribute. Perhaps you mean `.size`?

Comment: @kindall thank you! that fixed the shape attribute error, though now I am getting a read attribute error

Comment: You're calling `Image.open` twice, that can't be right.

Comment: Yes, either pass the filename into `make_square` and open in there, or open the image in your main code and pass the image object in (and don't open it in `make_square`).

Comment: And `make_square` isn't returning anything.

Comment: @MarkRansom the second block of code is a separate file where I imported the function, I was getting an error when I called the function without first defining the image file, but i don't think its right either at this point

Comment: @kindall to pass the image object in, would i define Image.open(file name) as a variable, and then call the variable?

Comment: Oh it's definitely not right. Your function either needs to take an image object as input or a filename string, it can't do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.

Firstly, you open the image twice - `image = Image.open('ca.jpg')`, and then inside your function in `im = Image.open(im)`. You only need either one of those.

Secondly, `crop` method expects a tuple with four values, defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate of the rectagular region the image will be cropped to. Your tuple has only two values.

Third, your function doesn't return anything. Instead of `print(im)`, you need to add `return im`. That way, in `imsquare = make_square(im1)` you assign the result of your function to imsquare.

With that you will be able to run your code. With that being said I don't think your cropping method is right. I am not exactly sure what cropping method you want, but here is how I would do it: After comparing `w` and `h` I'd assign the smaller value to a new variable:

```
if w > h: s=h
else: s=w
im = im.crop((0, 0, s, s))
return im
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help and explanations! It totally slipped past me that I needed 4 values for crop lol. And I'm supposed to crop the images from the upper left corner on their x-axes or their y-axes, depending on if the image is either wider or taller, so this is perfect thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

`size()` returns `(width, height)` tuple, and `crop()` takes a `(left, top, right, bottom)` tuple.

If you want to pass the cropped image back from the function, then you have to return it.

This works for me:

```
from PIL import Image

def make_square(im):
    print(im.size)
    w, h = im.size
    d = min(w, h)
    x = (w-d)/2
    y = (h-d)/2
    im = im.crop((x, y, d+x, d+y))
    print(im)
    return im

image = Image.open('ca.jpg')
imsquare = make_square(image)
imsquare.show()
```